# Start print process - Application not found

Tags: c#, file, pdf, printing, process

I have a problem, when I try to print a pdf file. I get an error message saying that the application don't exists. Any ideas? Here is my code.
Update:
It fails on print and printto, same error..

```
 if (!File.Exists(filename))
 {
      Console.WriteLine("The file is not found");
      return;
 }
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
 info.FileName = filename;
 info.Arguments = "\"" + printer + "\"";
 info.CreateNoWindow = false;
 info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 info.UseShellExecute = true;
 info.Verb = "printto";
 info.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
 try
 {
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
 }
```

And the error message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.dll
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Application not found
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at myControl.Print.SendToPrinter(String filename, String printer)
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: yes, I have now.. but still no sucess.. I am 90% sure this should work.. All information I can find is looking similar..

Comment: Did you check if `printto` is in the list of verbs for that file type? Did you make sure that the printer address is in the correct form?

Comment: Yes, "printto" is the third option. The print adress is picked up from :
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters